# How do I update skype through snap in ubuntu?

Tags: updates, skype, snap

Skype just told me there's a new version and I need to update it through package manager, how do I do that? Do I need to use the snap command? If so, then how? Ubuntu software center doesn't give me the option to update.

Comment: when installed using snap skype fails to auto launch on boot up even though its told to in skype settings so I prefer using the ubuntu package instead of snap

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have installed the Skype snap package, you can update it by running the following command in Terminal

```
snap refresh skype
```

If you have installed Skype deb package downloaded from their official website, then run

```
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux
```

Comment: Hey, so I did that and it says:"snap "skype" has no updates available", however if restart skype, it still says that I need to update.

Comment: it says "Skype version 8.16.0.4 Calling version 2018.07.01.5"

Comment: @Pavel Strange! It seems that is the latest version. Even the deb package available at their [official webpage](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/) is of version 8.16.0.4. I also have the same version, but I don't see any message like that.

Comment: Is it possible they didn't put the latest version on the download page? and the latest version is only available via update? Anyhow, since I restarted skype the last time, it hasn't told me to update anymore, even though when I ran "snap refresh skype" it told me there are no updates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both the snap package and deb package from their repo are of v8.16.0.4. It's unlikely there's a newer version.

Comment: maybe when I restarted skype, it updated automatically somehow.

Comment: Mine said there was an update, and after restarting it seems there isn't one. Possibly a glitch their end.

Comment: I got the same issue. It seems the only way to update Skype, installed via snap, is to kill the processes. After that, snap will auto-refresh Skype. `sudo killall skype` did not work. I had to find all of the pids and use `sudo kill pid pid pid etc`.